# how to execute a camel route defined only in spring from eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, spring, jms, apache-camel, dsl

Can anyone of you give me a step by step approach to execute a route after you it has been defined. The route is defined in spring DSL there is no java class with main method. Am using Eclipse IDE so please guide accordingly

My question more precisely is this can you run a route without a java class containing main method

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to using [camel-maven plugin](http://camel.apache.org/camel-maven-plugin.html) and run the mvn camel:run with the help of  m2eclipse. You just need to make sure you update the pom.xml with camel maven plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Camel provides you with a class that contains a main() method. Two, actually. One for starting a Spring context, the other for projects that do not employ spring.

In Eclipse, right-click your project, select "Run As -> Java Application". In the dialog enter "org.apache.camel.spring.Main" for the Class with the main() method. That's it.